# React: how to fire useeffect using context variable as dependency?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, use-context

I was trying to figure out how to fire a useEffect when its dependency is a useContext variable. My Context has an "update" variable, which at one point changes, but the effect isn't fired.

```
import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react"
import context from "./Context"

const Layout = () => {
    const ctx = useContext(context)
    const [updateState, setUpdateState] = useState(ctx.update)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("effect fired")
    }, [updateState])

    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

I tested whether the issue was my context "update" variable not changing, but it does. I will appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you used `useState`. This in effect memoized/froze the value of `updateState`, to the first run of this component.

You see `useState` takes a single arg (default value). Which is only used on the first render of the component, to populate `updateState`. When `ctx.update` changes, `useState` already has a default to set `updateState` to, so it is ignored.

Instead, you can remove `useState` completely...

```
import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react"
import context from "./Context"

const Layout = () => {
    const { update as updateState } = useContext(context);
    // Notice I have removed the useState.

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("effect fired")
    }, [updateState])

    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: I made a simple button and onclick that console logs the updateState variable and it appears unchanged even though the context value did change. I'm not sure how to verify whether maybe I'm setting the actual value in the context wrong?

Comment: never mind, i placed the context provider in the wrong spot, and thank you for help mr Aron